# Typescript(ts 1337) Trying to make an object keyable to values only matching static members of a Class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a dictionary where the keys are static members of a class (FabPerms) and the values are Arrays of `FabPerm`

Typescript seems to know what I'm trying to do. It shows me that it is reading the values correctly, but it's giving me an error.

Is there a way to do this? I've tried several varieties of `key in`, `keyof`, `keyof typeof`

The relevant mockup of code:

```
class FabPerm() {
  constructor(private name:string) {
    FabPerms._values.push(this);
  }
}

class FabPerms{
  static _values: any = [];

  static role1 = FabPerm('role1');
  static role2 = FabPerm('role2');
  static role3 = FabPerm('role3');
}

var permissions: { [key:keyof Omit<typeof FabPerms, `_${string}` | 'prototype'>]: FabPerm[] } = {};
//should accept any/all of the keys role1, role2, role3.
```

[image]

Comment: "consider using a mapped type instead" - `[key in keyof Omit<...`

Comment: I swear I tried `key in keyof`. I probably did with some other variant. thanks!